# How to make reverse (100% to 0%) progress page loader using Pace.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, loader, pace.js

I am using [Pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/) progress loader for page loader before content loads. Here what I want is the loader starts with **100% and goes down to 0% or 1%** instead of 0% to 100%.

- Start Load Percentage should be: 100%
- End Load Percentage should be either 0% or 1%

I looked into the Pace JS plugin but I am not able to figure out if that is possible or not. And if possible, what to change and where?

Please help !

Comment: does not seem to be doable easily..

Comment: Any workaround or do you know any other JS who can help me in this situation?

Comment: Why do you have to use this plugin?  Just write your own code.  This isn't difficult to do.  We can't tell you how to do it because you haven't provided enough specifics.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you reply. I have changed the progress-text in Pace js and its working now.